# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime equivalent for .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to update a .NET 2.0 website to include a function to convert time from a time zone to another.

Unfortunately I cannot use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime in .NET 2.0.

Is there any equivalent or workaround that takes into account Daylight Savings time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yup similar, so there is no solution for this?

Comment: The only solution would be via the p/invoke methods shown in the link Jon Skeet gave.  Or upgrade your .Net site to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these libraries for similar functionality in .Net 2.0:

- [ZoneInfo](http://www.codeplex.com/zoneinfo)
- [TZ4Net](http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm)

Comment: thanks Lance, but I'm only making a simple change on an existing website, adding a library might be a bit too much

Comment: Those libraries are for the Olson database anyway.  If he's using `TimeZoneInfo` in .Net 3.5+, then he needs the windows timezone database.

Comment: @MattJohnson: The question was regarding options available only in .Net 2.0.